# How can I reach flash scope variables if pages are in different paths? JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf-2, flash-scope

Why flash scope variables could not be reachable if view path is different?

I have source page:

```
/pages/order/order_view.jsf
```

And target page is in different path:

```
/pages/offer/offer_edit.jsf
```

I have set flash variable after submit on page order_view.jsf but when I redirect to the offer_edit.jsf, flash scope variables have been lost.

If I place two pages in same path I can reach flash scope variables after redirect;

```
/pages/order/order_view.jsf
/pages/order/offer_edit.jsf
```

Is it possible to reach flash scope variables after redirect If I put pages in different path? Where they are stored, is it cookie?

I am using javax.faces-2.1.13.jar

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug which is reported as [issue 2136](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2136) and fixed in Mojarra 2.1.14.